# How to use .after() as .html() if element exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('div').after('<p>this element should be unique</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>this is a div</div>
<button>click</button>
```

As you see, when I click on that `<button>` several times, I will see multiple element which have created, like this:

```
<div>this is a div</div>
<p>this element should be unique</p>
<p>this element should be unique</p>
<p>this element should be unique</p>
<button>click</button>
```

but I want to **append** that `<p>` after `<div>` only if it isn't exist, otherwise I want to **replace** it. Anyway I want this output: *(both for one time clicking and multiple times clicking)*

```
<div>this is a div</div>
<p>this element should be unique</p>
<button>click</button>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Change `.on('click'` to `.one('click'`

Comment: @j08691 Actually in reality I need to execute that function every time user clicks on that `button`, not just one time.

Comment: why do you want to use .after() and not .html() ?

Comment: @KWeiss Because there isn't any wrapper.

Comment: why not use a wrapper?

Comment: @KWeiss It's hard to explain it. I just can say: I'm not able to change the html structure and create a wrapper for that purpose.

Comment: @stack You can add the wrapper using JS/jQuery, without changing the HTML source.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Better add a wrapper, and just replace its contents:

```js
var $target = null;
$('button').on('click', function(){
  if(!$target) $target = $('<div></div>').insertAfter('div');
  $target.html('<p>this element should be unique</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>this is a div</div>
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: This is not what he are asking for.

Comment: Without making some assumptions about the layout and the code, I don't think there is any other way which works in general.

Comment: You are only replacing, he want to use after and html. So you need to start inserting and after replacing.

Comment: May you please tell me replacing an element with another one is possible or not? here is my current structure `<div></div><p></p>` and I want this structure `<div></div><span></span>` *(I replaced `<p>` with `<span>`)*. Is that possible?

Comment: @stack Yes, you can use any HTML string. But note that in the DOM it will be wrapped inside a `div` element, like `<div>this is a div</div><div><p>...</p></div>` or `<div>this is a div</div><div><span>...</span></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how you're generating that `<p>` elements, here you can check some generic solution, and `implement` your own logic

```js
var text;
$('#text').on('change', function() {
  text = $(this).val();

});
   $('button').on('click', function() {

  if ($('div').next('p:contains(' + text + ')').length) {

  } else {
    $('div').next('p').remove();
    $('div').after('<p>' + text + '</p>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text">
<div>this is a div</div>
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: Well that's not what I need, I need to replace new content ..! Not just prevent of appending.

Comment: @stack I edited the answer, still not sure how you're using that code. check the snippet

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if the element exists, and if it does update the content.  Something like this should work:

```
var index = 0;

$('button').on('click', function(){
index++;

    if($('#myWrapper').length == 0) {
        $('div').after('<p id="myWrapper">this element should be unique' + index +'</p>');
    } else {
        $('#myWrapper').html('<p>this element should be unique' + index +'</p>');
    }
});
```

JS Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/44mgz316/3/

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Oriol Yes you are right, it can be problematic, actually the main problem is lack of wrapper ..

Comment: @Oriol, the snipets are maked based on the example gived, in that case
<div>this is a div</div>
<p>this element should be unique</p>
<button>click</button>

Comment: @stack Exactly. That's why I answered you should add a wrapper. You should clarify why you can't change the structure and add a wrapper.

Comment: @stack why not just include an id when adding the tag?  I updated the answer with a better example.

Comment: @Oriol Look, I know, your solution is most standard. But I'm a part of a team, my duty is just js-coding. I don't access to HTML codes.

Comment: @AdamKonieska Adding an ID is a good idea, in case the HTML string is known beforehand

Answer (score 1):

If you will have only one p

edited

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  if (!($('div').next('p').length)) {
    $('div').after('<p>this element should be unique</p>');
  }else{
    $('div').next('p').html('this will replace');
  }
});
```

Comment: that is bad, you're putting a <p> inside the <p>

Comment: I didn't notice that KWeiss, have only copy pasted.

Comment: @KWeiss I mean of *"that's not bad"* was the idea of this answer.